# Configurable keyboard shortcut without using content scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts, global, content-script

Chrome Extension: I am looking for a way to assign global keyboard shortcuts that can be invoked even when the current tab has no content (and hence no content script). Some examples of such tabs: 'new tab' tabs, chrome://extensions tabs, 'page not loaded' tabs, etc  Use cases for such a requirement are operations like close tab, go to next/prev tab, etc.

The [chrome.commands](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) api allows one to do this. However, there seems to be no way for the user to configure these keyboard shortcuts, which is something I'd really want my extension to allow.

Is there any way to get *configurable* keyboard shortcuts that don't need a content script?

Comment: Thanks to your question I was able to create https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/global-new-tab-shortcut/dcngopenklmnfdlfocljeaokkhcplong?hl=en-US which opens a new chrome tab from anywhere :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shortcut for [`chrome.commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) cannot be changed by the extension, but it is configurable by the user. This interface is built-in and offered by Chrome itself.

Visit the extensions page, scroll down and click on the **Configure commands** link. A box will be shown, where the user can set the preferred shortcut:

[image]

<sup>The code for the "Remap shortcut" extension is posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429178/override-the-bookmark-shortcut-ctrld-function-in-chrome/13430063#13430063).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that is really neat! Another related question: can one give a link within the extensions options.html page to get to this interface (so that this feels more integrated with the extension's settings)?

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya You can't link to `chrome://extensions/`, but you can use `chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://extensions/'});` to open the page (instruct the user to scroll down before opening the page though).

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I guess that's asking for too much, but I suppose there is no way to link to the 'Configure commands' link directly?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to simply open the extensions page... nothing more

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya Ah. The anchor only works if the page is already open, because the content is dynamically generated. You have to tell the user to scroll down (a screenshot / screencast might help).

Comment: Damn. But I guess I was expecting too much. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Can an extension programmatically access (read only) the `chrome.commands` shortcuts that belong to it, and find what the user specified values of those shortcuts are?

Comment: [`chrome.commands.getAll`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html#method-getAll) yields a list of [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html#type-Command), each ought have a shortcut property.

Comment: Now you can point your user to this dialog with chrome://extensions/configureCommands