# Google Chrome Extension Load Content Script on all pages including "chrome://" pages and the "New Tab" page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Chrome Extension which uses some shortcut keys, set using a Content Script. The shortcuts work on all http:// and https:// pages, but I would like the keyboard shortcuts to also be loaded on a user's "New Tab" page as well as on any "chrome://" pages. I am not sure if this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I included the relevant parts of my current manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://*/*", "storage" 
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: You can't use content scripts on those pages.

Comment: Not possible. Consider using the `chrome.commands` API, see [Override the bookmark shortcut (Ctrl+D) function in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429178/override-the-bookmark-shortcut-ctrld-function-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can now replace the default new tab page with an HTML page from the extension. [More information here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/override/). (You can also override the bookmarks and history pages, but not all from the same extension.)

Extensions cannot access any other chrome:// urls.