# unable to use event.preventDefault() with chrome

Tags: javascript, ctrl

I am using **ctrl + charCode**s in order to delete a row from the listing page which is working fine on firefox but when I tested it on **Chrome**, the **event.preventDefault()** couldn't stop the browser based function to come up

```
function showkey(e){
     if(e.ctrlKey && e.charCode == 100){  
        e.preventDefault();
        //delete code // }

<body onkeypress="showkey(event);">
```

Comment: use e.stopPropagation() as well, to stop bubbling

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive with jQuery. Include jQuery library

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 100)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

This works :)

Answer (score 0):

look this answer
[Override the bookmark shortcut (Ctrl+D) function in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429178/override-the-bookmark-shortcut-ctrld-function-in-chrome)

working solution just tested on this page

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) === 'D') {
    console.log("you pressed ctrl-D");
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
```